# A simpler alternative of JSON

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a main table in PostgreSQL db and I have some other small tables. I want to add every single small table to the main table's column **with non-binary format**. So, it seems, I will use JSON but is there any alternative of this? Any simpler, any lighter?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume this is only the option

Comment: There's also [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/hstore.html) but the primary question is probably why?

Comment: For searching alternatives? It's just curious. :)

Comment: Still, it would be helpful to know your motivation..

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve here? Why not simply join the tables?

Comment: It's not about me, I am dealing with a customer's problem and that's what my teammates told me.

Comment: you can also use array of custom composite type

Comment: And what is that "customer's problem"?

Comment: Letting someone else solve the problems never leads to good results ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you know the data format "outband" (in your application), you can, of course, reduce the overhead, by omitting the keys.

Example: You want to store fruits and the continent where they primarily appear (stupid example maybe..). As JSON, it could be

```json
[
  {
    "fruit": "apple",
    "continent": "europe"
  },
  {
    "fruit": "banana",
    "continent": "asia"
  },
  {
    "fruit": "cherry",
    "continent": "australia"
  }
]
```

If your application knows the data format, it could be:

```
apple|europe
banana|asia
cherry|australia
```